# Get instanced object by String

Tags: java, string, object, field

Is it possible to get a Object that is instanced in the Code by a String at Runtime?

Somthing like that:

```
public String xyz = "aaaa_bbb";

getObject("xyz").some function of String (e.g.: .split("_"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Reflection is what you probably want. But it's also likely that a simple `HashMap` can do what you really need it for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example

If it's a class field, you can get it by name like this.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class Test {


    public String stringInstance = "first;second";

    public void Foo() {


        try {
            Object instance = getClass().getDeclaredField("stringInstance").get(this);
            Method m = instance.getClass().getMethod("split", String.class);

            Object returnValue = m.invoke(instance, ";");
            if(returnValue instanceof String[])
            {
                for(String s : (String[])returnValue )
                {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        new Test().Foo();
    }



}
```

If it's a local method variable you are trying to invoke on, then you might be able to get at to the variable in from the current method from the call stack  `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` maybe.

Comment: Hello, i have already implement like you but this is my problem: m.invoke(stringInstance, ";");,  stringInstance should be a String like m.invoke("stringInstance", ";")

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to make out what you are asking, but you can fetch field values by name using reflection.  Something like this:

```
    Class c = this.getClass();  // or Someclass.class
    Field f = c.getDeclaredField("xyz");
    String value = (String) f.get(this);
    ... = value.split("_");
```

(I've left out a lot of exception handling ...)

But as a comment points out, if you are really trying to implement an associative array, there are better ways of doing this in Java; e.g. using a `Map` class.

Comment: I have custom components on a jPanel and i would like to work with them without repainting them. I knwo if i use a List or Map that it is possible but i have to change the value in the Map and then repaint the GUI with the infomration in the Map.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to rephrase the question.

If you just want to get the "aaaa" and "bbb" strings from the initial string, you can use [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your String is a member field of your object, you can go take a look at the [`Field`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class.

However, I have to warn you that the code that you'll end up with will be by far longer than what you expect here. Indeed, you'll have to do some operations :

1. Get the Field obejct associated to xyz
2. Get method from its name and parameters list (using as an example [`Class#getDeclaredMethod(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29))
3. Invoke the method on this particular instance

Each of these steps will eb a rather obscure line of code, with a bunch of throwed exceptions.

So, if you have an alternative, well, use it !

Answer (score -1):

I have custom components on a jPanel and i would like to work with them without repainting them. I knwo if i use a List or Map that it is possible but i have to change the value in the Map and then repaint the GUI with the infomration in the Map.

Comment: Doesn't seem an answer this one to me.