# Can I access objects using their names in a String Variable in Java

Tags: java

I have some set of objects defined. Can I access any of them by passing these object names through a String variable ?

Comment: You can with reflection. But what are you trying to achieve? See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092972/get-instanced-object-by-string

Comment: I defined some objects like suiteTest1,suiteTest2 in my base class. In another class Iam trying to access these objects by passing their names dynamically into a String col3. So col3.testmethod() should do the same as that suiteTest1.testmethod() or suiteTest2.testmethod() should be doing. How can I do that ? Plz Help

Comment: Your description is rather unclear, shouldn't you use interfaces if you want to decouple the method invocation from being class specific? If you actually provide the code it might be easier to understand. And please, add the code to the original question, not to a comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked and answered **many** times before on this site, and always you need to understand that variable names are not as important as they seem, and almost don't even exist in compiled code.

The canonical answer for this: If you want to access an object by a String, use a Map.

For example if you want to access a JTextField based on a String, you could use a `HashMap<String, JTextField>` and put in your String / JTextField pairs. And then later when you want to get the proper JTextField, call `get(key)` on the map passing in the appropriate String key.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are about to do, there is a easier way of solving your problem. If you instead explain what you are trying to solve it will be easier to answer.
But as Hovercraft just posted, using a Map is generally a good idea if you want to access objects by a Name, or number or anything for that matter. Maps are really good to use.

Comment: Following is an object in my base class: suiteHome = new Xls_Reader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\jamo\\xls\\AnritsuSuite.xlsx"); I am trying to access the methods of Xls_Reader object by providing the name of its object reference "suiteHome" in a String variable..something like String col3="suiteName". So can I now access the object as col3.testmethods() instead of suiteHome.testmethods() ?

Comment: You added the comment in the wrong place, should be added to your original question via edit. Either way, it makes no sense, I can't understand what you are trying achieve.

Comment: @user3212073: you're going about it wrong and have described a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Rather than telling us what code you're trying to solve, you should instead tell us what overall problems you are trying to solve, because your current approach is surely an incorrect one.

Comment: My requirement is, I have about 10 objects created in my base class. I need to be able to access any of these objects by dynamically passing their names through a variable. Is it possible ? In my scenario, I should be able to access these objects by providing these objects names in xls sheet column.I am able to read the xls file and the column (defined as String array) into my script but  the script throws an error argument mismatch.

Comment: Yes, a Map, which has been mentioned already.